# Where can I find the google cloud messaging library, before it used firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Does any one have, or know where i can find the google cloud messaging library from before it started using firebase?

I know that it is advised to update to firebase but this is out of scope.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just install it with Cocoapods with the last version of the pod before Firebase:

```
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging', '2.0.4'
```